# Required Parameter (*) in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012, rdl

I am looking for ideas as to how can we have a (*) sign on a required report parameter (SSRS).
One quick idea that comes is to add this symbol in the label itself, is there any parameter setting that enables us to do this?

PS: Apologies if this question sounds dumb :)

Answer (score 0):

All parameters are required unless you see allow Blank Value or Null value or you set default values, which would allow your report to run without values or using default ones.

So it would look like the answer is to use an Asterisk (*) in the Parameter Prompt.